How validate number length in ozzo-go
I'm trying to use ozzo for validating a phone number with fixed length of 13. how can I achieve that with ozzo?
Here is my code:
func RequestCheker(request api.User)  error {
    return validation.ValidateStruct(&request,
        validation.Field(&request.Phone, validation.Required, validation.Length(12,13)),
        validation.Field(&request.Firstname, validation.Required, validation.Length(3, 65)),
        validation.Field(&request.Lastname, validation.Required, validation.Length(3, 65)),
        validation.Field(&request.Password, validation.Required, validation.Length(4, 40)),
    )
}

api.User type:
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    UUID      uint32 `gorm:"unique"`
    Phone     int `json:"phone" gorm:"unique"`
    Firstname string `json:"firstname"`
    Lastname  string `json:"lastname"`
    Password  string `json:"password"`
}

how can I validate the number to have fixed length of 13?
what I've tried
I tried converting it from int to string and rune but I got this error for both scenario:
field #0 cannot be found in the struct


Why make the phone an int, and not a string?

that way you can measure the length much better but since I'm storing the phone number in the database its faster and more efficient to store number instead of string so database can find it faster when you request the specific number between millions results but you might say that validate it using string type then convert it back to INT and it will work but I think its possible to validate in int type I just want to use the most simple way to do it

this might not be standard solution for this but it will work.
instead of using:
validation.Field(&request.Phone, validation.Required, validation.Length(12,13)),

we can use :
validation.Field(&request.Phone, validation.Required, validation.Min(1000000000000), validation.Max(999999999999))

this will work for making sure the length would be fixed 13 but I am looking forward to a better approach for this, like making a custom rule for ozzo
